# Return struct array c++

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to return a struct from a function, but I get the error:

> [Error] could not convert '(Data*)(& data)' from 'Data*' to 'Data'

This is my struct:

```
struct Data
{
    string id, marc, model;
};
```

And this is what I actually trying to do to return the struct:

```
Data ReadFile (string file)
{
Data data[200];
ifstream in;
in.open(file.c_str(), ios::in);
if(!in) 
{
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    main();
}
else
{
    int i=0;
    while(getline(in, data[i].id, '\n'))
    {
        getline(in, data[i].marc, '\n');
        getline(in, data[i].model, '\n');
        i++;
    }
    in.close();
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    main();
}
return data;
}
```

So, what is the best way to return a struct, i need it in other functions,
thanks.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Data>` instead of `Data data[200];`.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to call `main()` anywhere. I'm sure you can achieve the same effect with some loops and if's.

Comment: I suppose in this case `std::array<Data, 200>` would be more appropriate than `std::vector<Data>`, since you already know the size of the array. No need to waste dynamic memory.`

Comment: It is in fact undefined behaviour to call `main()` yourself in C++

Comment: @DeiDei it seems to me that the code is supposed to read a file,  so the vector would be more appropriate (and OP probably used fixed size array because he did not know about runtime-sized containers)

Comment: Can you please show us how data are stored in your file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the structure of your function:

```
Data ReadFile (string file)
// ^ this function returns a 'Data' class
{
    Data data[200];
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^ here you declare a LOCAL array of 200 'Data's
    // ... stuff ...
    return data;
    //     ^^^^ here you try to return a 'Data*' 
}
```

Here we have two problems (not to mention any design consideration):

- You are trying to return a pointer instead of a single structure as expected by the declaration of the function.
- The array 'data' is local, its lifetime is limited to the scope of the function.

Now, you could fix those issues by dynamically allocating memory for the array, returning that pointer after having changed the return value of the function to a pointer (and remember to delete somewhere), but what I'd recommend is to use a `std::vector` and leave all the memory management to the Standard Library classes.

```
std::vector<Data> ReadFile(std::string file)
{
    std::vector<Data> data;
    std::ifstream in{file};
    if ( !in ) 
    {
        cout << "Error opening file " << file << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Now, it's not clear how data are stored in your file.
        // Assuming something like:
        //   
        //   id1
        //   marc1
        //   model1
        //   id2 
        //   ...
        Data tmp;
        while(    getline(in, tmp.id) 
               && getline(in, tmp.marc)
               && getline(in, tmp.model) )
        {
            data.push_back(tmp);
        }
        std::cout << data.size() << " Data structs succesfully read.\n";
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The problem of your solution for me, is that the function must be: Data ReadFile (string);  I can not change that. I am going crazy about accesing that struc between functions...

Comment: @Gui61 if `Data` is the structure you posted, a function like `Data ReadFile(string)` will read (and return) only one struc at a time. Are you sure that the string you have to pass is a file name? Maybe your task is to use that function to transform a string (a single line read from a file) into a Data struct and you have to call it for every line read (in another function).

Comment: My idea is create a vector and add items to it, but I am going crazy to do it in c++, like this (struct Data data[200];)